# Dependent Continuous Random Variables

Tags: probability, random-variables

I am currently studying mathematics in college and I am having trouble with one of the assignments.

The question is: 
Let $Y$ be a number picked at random in $[0, 1]$. Given $Y=y$, suppose that $X$ is a random variable, such that $X\mid(Y=y)$ is a number picked at random in $[0,y]$. What is $\Pr(X\leqslant 1/2)$

I am thinking of the following - is $f(y)= y [ 0\leqslant y\leqslant 1]$ and $f(x) = x [ 0\leqslant x\leqslant y]$?

I am trying to find a way to integrate over the possible values for x and y so that I can find the resulting probability?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:
$$
P\left(X\leq \tfrac12\right)=\int_0^1 P\left(X\leq \tfrac12\mid Y=y\right)f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy.
$$

Comment: Thank you! Does something like this seem remotely correct?Unfortunately I have no idea how to paste LateX code in comments so I hope the following image will suffice. 
![Solution](http://i.imgur.com/i2m87DO.png)

Comment: Sorry had a typo in the equation up there - this should be more like it - ![Solution](http://i.imgur.com/Shxvr7M.png)

Comment: Almost, $P(X\leq \tfrac12\mid Y=y)$ has different expressions depending on whether $y\leq \tfrac12$ or $y>\tfrac12$.

Comment: Btw, Latex code in comments are just as in questions and answers: Just put \$ around the math.